# getElementById does not work after ajax call

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I'm developing a web application using javascript / ajax .

The problem is that in my application (a kind of social network) I need to read information about users (posts in a database). To do this I use a PHP dedicated service with the interactions with database. The service returns HTML formatted for the main page.

Now, I use this service with an AJAX call to bring the HTML and injects it into my page. The problem is that when I try to get an element from the injected HTML with javascript:

```
document.getElementById('commentsArea_xxx').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

`getElementById` returns `null`.

I think the problem is that after the AJAX call the browser does not update the document and so 'commentsArea_xxx' doesn't exist in the document!

How do I fix this problem?

This is my code:

```
function moreComments(id){
        var footerIcon = document.getElementById('footer');
            footerIcon.innerHTML="<div style='text-align:center;'><img src='images/home_selected.png' onClick='loadHome()'/><img id='cameraButton' src='images/camera.png'/><img src='images/list.png' onClick='loadMyVideo()'/></div>";
            pageOld=pageCurrent;
            pageCurrent=0;
            document.getElementById("ajaxContent").innerHTML="<div id='wrapper' style='top:95px;'><div id='scroller'><ul id='thelist'><li style='text-align:center;'><img src='images/loading.gif' style='text-align:center;'></li></ul></div></div>";
            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else{
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
                    document.getElementById("commentsArea_"+id).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                    loaded();
                    me();
                    setTimeout(function () {myScroll.refresh();}, 0);
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","home_more.php?id="+id,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

This should do it :

```
$('body').ajaxComplete(function () {
        document.getElementById('commentsArea_xxx').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
 });
```

This will be executed after every ajax call.

**UPDATE:**
If you have not added the element to the DOM go through @T.J Crowder's answer.

Comment: @AlessioMelani You should accept an answer, if it helped you. Peace!!

Answer (score 4):

> I think the problem is that after the ajax call does not update the document and so 'commentsArea_xxx' doesn't exist in document!!!

Right. All the ajax call does is bring the data to your code, on the `xmlhttp.responseText` property. It's up to you to add it to the document. You can do that by setting the `innerHTML` of an existing element, or by creating elements via [`document.createElement`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-2141741547) and appending them to the document via [`Element#appendChild`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-184E7107) / [`Element#insertBefore`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-952280727) / etc.

Check out the various [DOM specs](http://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR) for details. The HTML5 spec also has [some information](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#webappapis) on this.

---

FWIW, there's a **lot** of utility functionality and browser-difference-smoothing available in a good library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries). Leveraging the hard work people have put into these libraries lets you focus on writing code for your specific value-add.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is as you state: ... the ajax call does not update the document... Rather, the javascript AFTER the call to retrieve the php file via AJAX occurs before the DOM has a chance to refresh.  However, setTimeout() behaves nicely in that it gives the DOM a bit of time to refresh, then you can put any trailing javascript code within a setTimeout function.  At least it works with IE 11, FF 28, Chrome 33 and Opera 11.  A delay of nine milliseconds works for me. So I suggest you put any javascript that follows the AJAX call inside a setTimeout() function:

```
setTimeout(function(){
// Your Code here
    var aVariable = document.getElementById("idRenderedFromAJAX");
}, 9);
```

The other thing is to let xmlhttp.responseText return its value to a javascript variable that is already connected to the DOM prior to making the AJAX call. Then, any HTML that is rendered via the call will be accessible via a refreshed DOM using, say, getElementById from code placed wuthin the setTimeout function.  Just a suggestion as this alternative does not require jquery and does not seem to be floating around on the web.