# Can't get table data using GetElementById in Javascript/AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Here is my JavaScript function.

```
var ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest;
ajaxRequest.open("GET", "crudops.aspx?StudentId="+id+"&StudentName="+name+"&operation=insert", false);
ajaxRequest.send(null);
document.getElementById("TableDiv").innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
var t = document.getElementById("TableDiv").innerHTML;
alert(t);
var row = table.insertRow(0);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
cell1.innerHTML = id;
cell2.innerHTML = name;
```

Here is what is there inside t.

```
<table id="studenttable" cellpadding="5"><tbody><tr><th>Student Id</th><th>Student Name</th> ... </table>
```

But I'm unable to read table into a variable using something like

```
var table = t.getElementbyId("studenttable");
```

How to read that table and append rows?
help me with suggestions.

Comment: What do you get if you `console.log(ajaxRequest.responseText);`?

Comment: whole `TableDiv` HTML code @caramba

Comment: `var row = table.insertRow(0);` what is `table` ? You have only `t`, not `table` man. Also `innerHTML` returns a string!!

Comment: Read first [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13539769/2008111) then [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5447978/2008111) and then [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13467331/2008111) I would stick with the second link. I think that is the most simple to use.

Comment: ajax is `asynchronous` - the response is not guaranteed to arrive immediately after the request is sent but your code is trying to use the response in a synchronous manner. Use a callback function to process the response and manipulate the DOM

Answer (score 1):

```
var t = document.getElementById("TableDiv").innerHTML;
var table = t.getElementById("studenttable");
```

t varible shoud be an element, not a string. Try to delete `.innerHTML;`.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the nature of asynchronous requests you need to assign a callback function to process the response data rather than expect the response immediately

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
xhr.onreadystatechane=function(){
    if( xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200 ){

        document.getElementById("TableDiv").innerHTML = xhr.response;
        var t = document.getElementById("TableDiv").innerHTML;
        alert(t);

        var row = table.insertRow(0);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

        cell1.innerHTML = id;
        cell2.innerHTML = name;     

    }
};
xhr.open( "GET", "crudops.aspx?StudentId="+id+"&StudentName="+name+"&operation=insert", true );
xhr.send(null);
```

Comment: I hadn't noticed the use of `false` for the synchronous flag

Answer (score 1):

- Set XHR `async` to `true` (or you can omit it)
- Use a `onreadystatechange` callback
- Don't refer to DOM Elements by `innerHTML` use the DOM Node Element Object  instead

***[jsBin live demo](http://jsbin.com/sinavip/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output)***

```
var id = "123",
    name = "This Is A Name";


var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    method = "GET",
    url = "crudops.aspx?StudentId="+id+"&StudentName="+name+"&operation=insert";

XHR.open(method, url, true); // << or omit async (anyway defaults to true)

XHR.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if(XHR.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && XHR.status === 200) {

    document.getElementById("TableDiv").innerHTML = XHR.responseText;

    // Use meaningful var names
    // var tableWrapper = document.getElementById("TableDiv").innerHTML;

    // BTW since at this point your table is (hopefully) in the DOM
    // you can go get it directly
    var table = document.getElementById("studenttable");

    if(!table) return; // Do nothing if no such Element in DOM

    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell1.innerHTML = id;
    cell2.innerHTML = name;

  }
};

XHR.send();
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open

Answer (score 0):

The letter "d" need to be uppercase.

var table = t.getElement**B**yId("studenttable");